# How to Read QLineEdit data dynamically

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt4

I am trying to create labels and textboxes dynamically in PyQt5 however, i have no idea how i can read data entered in the textboxes when a user hits the save button. My code looks as follows:

````
       self.setWindowTitle("Yaml --> Json")
       self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)

       self.createLayout()
       vbox = QVBoxLayout()
       for i in range(0, len(self.listItems)):
           vbox.addWidget(QLabel(list(self.listItems.keys())[i]))
           vbox.addWidget(QLineEdit())
       vbox.addWidget(self.groupBox)
       self.setLayout(vbox)
       self.show()

   def createLayout(self):
       self.groupBox = QGroupBox()
       hboxLayout = QHBoxLayout()

       button = QPushButton("Save", self)
       button.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon("save.png"))
       button.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(40, 40))
       button.setMinimumHeight(40)
       button.clicked.connect(self.ClickSave)
       hboxLayout.addWidget(button)

       button1 = QPushButton("Exit", self)
       button1.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon("exit.png"))
       button1.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(40, 40))
       button1.setMinimumHeight(40)
       button1.clicked.connect(self.ClickExit)
       hboxLayout.addWidget(button1)

       self.groupBox.setLayout(hboxLayout)

   def ClickExit(self):
       print("Exited!!")
       sys.exit()

   def ClickSave(self):
       print("Saved!")```
````

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just assign the widgets you want to access later to instance variables or store them in a list, e.g.

```
    self.line_edit_list = []
    for i in range(0, len(self.listItems)):
        vbox.addWidget(QLabel(list(self.listItems.keys())[i]))
        line_edit = QLineEdit()
        vbox.addWidget(line_edit)
        self.line_edit_list.append(line_edit)

    ....

    def ClickSave(self):
        for edit in self.line_edit_list:
            print(edit.text())
```